# jQuery lightbox, problems initiating

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox

so Im trying to get the following lightbox working on my site:-

http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/Responsive-Touch-enabled-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin.html

Here is my development site: dev.blupace.com

I have a test gallery .gallery with an id of hgallery 
This is hidden using

```
#hgal{
display: none;
}
```

I have the styesheet loaded

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/simplelightbox/simplelightbox.min.css">
```

and the the JS loaded after jQuery

```
   <!-- JQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap JS -->
<script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- custom JS -->
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>

<!-- Light Gallery -->
<script src="js/simplelightbox/simple-lightbox.min.js"></script>
```

In my custom JS i have the following code:-

```
var lightbox= $('.gallery a').simpleLightbox();

$('.btn-fashion').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    lightbox.open($('.gallery a:first'));
});
```

Which should initiate the lightbox and open the test gallery on clicking the .btn-fashion

The problem is that I just cannot get this to work, it seems like the lightbox is not initiating. So any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Kind regards,

Comment: There seem to be errors in your console. First, fix them and let us know if the issue still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to initiate your Lightbox before it is loaded due to loading your custom.js before the Lightbox script is loaded.You also need to load tether.js if your using bootstrap 4.

Rearrange the scripts like this ( and add tether.js):

```
 <!-- JQuery -->
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Tether -->
  <script>   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap JS -->
<script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Light Gallery -->
<script src="js/simplelightbox/simple-lightbox.min.js"></script>

<!-- custom JS -->
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment, I have done as you suggested and also uploaded the changes to my dev server, however the lightbox still does not open. I still get the same error TypeError: $('.gallery a').simpleLightbox is not a function. (In '$('.gallery a').simpleLightbox()', '$('.gallery a').simpleLightbox' is undefined)

Comment: My mistake, i loaded the wrong script... sheesh.... thanks for the awesome help, worked perfectly....